# TOC alignment in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir

I'm trying to get chapters and sections to line up in a memoir ToC as:

```
Chapter one        Chapter title
                   Section title
                   Another section
                   A third section

Chapter two        Second chapter title 
                   Another etc.
```

I really can't fathom the pseudo code on p.158 of the manual but I've tried setting widths for `\cftpartnumwidth` and `\cftchapternumwidth` but I can't get these boxes to work. My code:

```
% part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{4.0cm}

% chapter
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{4.0cm}
\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\hfill}
\renewcommand*{\chapternumberline}[1]{\cftchaptername \numtoname #1  \cftchapteraftersnum}

% section
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{4.0cm}
```

I can control the section title placement, but something is breaking the chapter title placement (I presume the renewal definition of `\cftchapteraftersnum`.

Can anyone give me the spell? thanks

==============================
UPDATE:

I modified the code with Gonzalo's suggestion to:

```
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\chaptername\hspace{3em}}

% part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\addtolength\cftpartnumwidth{\mylen}

% chapter
\addtolength\cftchapternumwidth{\mylen}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpresnum{\chaptername~} 

% section
\renewcommand\cftsectionindent{\dimexpr\mylen+1.5em\relax}
```

But it gives this: 
[image]

The "Sections" are not lining up with the "Chapters"...

Comment: Does your diagram mean that sectional unit numbering must be suppressed?

Comment: Yes. And I alsop need to add "Part"

Comment: please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code does what you want (change the value of the length `\chapind`  according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength\chapind
\setlength\chapind{2.8cm}% change according to your needs

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{\chapind}

\renewcommand*{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
\parbox[t]{\chapind}{\chaptername~\numtoname#1\cftchapteraftersnum}%
}

\renewcommand\cftsectionindent{\dimexpr\chapind-2.1em\relax}
\makeatletter
\def\cftsectionpresnum #1\@cftasnum{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{Test Part One}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\section{Section One Three}

\part{Test Part Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}
\section{Section Two Three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo but I don't quite understand why it's still not working. I omitted to point out I need "Parts" as well, with the Part number aligning on the left margin and the part titles aligning with the chapter and section titles. I don't know how to post my code and the resulting file on here - I apologise.

Comment: @Richard: simply saying "it's not working" is useless. Please edit your original question with a minimal document showing the current settings relevant to this issue and perhaps including my code and illustrating the problems you are having.

Comment: I'm doing my best. I have never used this facility before and the editing process is confusing. I tried to enter it in this box and it only gave me 500 characters, which wasn't enough to post the code, and nowhere to put a screenshot.

Comment: @Richard: that's why I said that you should add an edit to your original question.

Comment: Well I was busy editing the original question while you were saying it. Anyway, I appreciate your help - thank you.

Comment: @Richard: please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: I had to use `\renewcommand\cftsectionindent{\dimexpr\chapind\relax}`, but it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and patience. Now all I have to do is study it and try to figure out what you did :)

Comment: @Richard: you're welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer (by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count) if you consider that it solved your problem.